# A problem on multinomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that an experiment can result in one of $r$ possible outcomes, the $i$th outcome having probability $p_i$, $i=1,\dots,r, \sum _{i=1} ^{r}p_i =1$. Let $X_i$ denote the number of times the $i$-th outcome appears, $i=1,\dots,r$. What is the probability mass function of $\sum _{i=1} ^{k}X_i $ ?

I tried to use law of total probability and break this into the probabilities $P(X_i=k)$. But, I am not able to find any closed form expression.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution

Comment: @dato: Thanks for your reply. Please note that I asked a specific question on multinomial distribution

Answer (score 2):

[image]

i hope this will help you.it is definiton of    probability mass function,additional  material please read on wikipedia,i have posted  link

also please consider this link

http://dspace.library.cornell.edu/bitstream/1813/9252/1/TR001375.pdf